# Where to Use bigint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bigint

I have this application which I am developing for our government. It would store details of governments contracts, contractors, tenders, schemes, schemeProgress etc

Now in some places I have user BIGINT i.e. in tblSchemeProgress, I have made the ProgressID as BIGINT because I assumed that this project is going to be forever in the gov departments and it's going to store really huge amount of data becasue government issues multiples of tenders and schemes and then storing each scheme details for ever so INT might not be sufficient to store so I chose BIGINT,

Did I do correct ? Am I right to use BIGINT here ?

Comment: Well, are you expecting more than 2,147,483,647 records?

Comment: int is more than sufficient.

Comment: Just to put it in context - if you were generating, on average, 3 entries per second, 24x7, an `int` would still be sufficient for over 20 years of usage. Do you really anticipate that sort of usage?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:- That is really a good way to make anyone understand the maximum limits :)

Comment: With `INT`, you get **over 2 billion** values - if you insert a row **every second**, all day, every day, all year round -- you need **66.5 years** before you hit that limit.

With `BIGINT`, you get **over 9 quintillion** possible values - if your app inserts **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hitting that limit ....

Comment: Well, in the Data Warehouse environments I work with are lots of tables with more than  2,147,483,647 rows, so it always depends on the anticipated number, for employees & contractors an INT should be enough, but what if your company is so successful to get more than 2 billion customers or bills? At least there are over 7 billion potential customers in the world :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bigint when you are sure that your records are going to [exceed the value (2,147,483,647)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187745.aspx) which is basically the maximum limit of int data type.

The maximum limit for big int is `2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`

My suggestion is to use `int` in most of the cases if you are looking to make it as an id column of you table. If you think that your column will involve calculations as well for which the value may exceed the maximum range of int then you can make that column as BIGINT.